# PHP select logged in user, not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I can't get the logged in user in the code, can you please help me to figure it out:

the code which is not working:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '$_SESSION['user']['username']'")
            or die(mysql_error());
```

but it is working for showing it thought, in here:

```
echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do NOT use mysql functions anymore.

Comment: What's "not working"?  What's the problem?  What happens?  Do you see any errors?

Comment: Try `"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '{$_SESSION['user']['username']}'"`.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this. The first is to define a new variable to contain the `$_SESSION['user']['username']` value and the second is to enclose `$_SESSION['user']['username']` in curly braces (see: [Strings - variable parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more information).

**Solution 1**

```
$username = $_SESSION['user']['username'];

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '$username'")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

**Solution 2**

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '{$_SESSION['user']['username']}'")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

In addition to this, if one is only accessing the top-level of the array (e.g. `$_SESSION['username']` rather than `$_SESSION['user']['username']`) one can simply remove the quotes around the key name:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '$_SESSION[username]'")
        or die(mysql_error());
```

---

However, it should be worth pointing out that [`mysql` functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should look into using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, please avoid using mysql functions anymore, and this not a hackproof code. Pleae make it

```
   $user = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE user = '".$user."'")
        or die(mysql_error());
```